# Creating REST Api bean

Tags: java, jira-rest-java-api

I was wondering it there is any good way without creating separate bean and breaking DRY principle if I want to expose different values.

For example here is the "GET" bean :

```
class NameBean {
    @XMLAttribute
    String name;
    int    age;
    String ssn;
}
```

But when I "POST" I wont need ssn. Do I really have to create another bean if I don't want "ssn" in the json.

```
class PostNameBean {
   @XMLAttribute
    String name;
    int    age;
}
```

Comment: isn't there an optional annotation somewhere?

Comment: Tried to find it, dosent seem to be.

Comment: how is this related to both jira and spring? can you post a link to the system you are using?

Comment: Spring tag should not have been there.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass nillable = true on your ssn field and clearly document that the field is not required when the user posts the data.

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp